# A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression Linqkit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linqkit

I have one expression , for example `x=>x.Id` ;

And I have a function, where I need to combine two expressions. I use Linqkit .

My model:

```
public class Model{
   Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> Expr {get;set;}
}

public Model Combine(Model input)
{
   var exp = x => input.Expr.Invoke(x) && x.Name.Contains("A");
   input.Expr = exp;
   input.Expr.Compile();
   return input;
}
```

Than I want to pass it in my repository, where I need to sort my entity.

```
public Ienumerable<Entity> Get(Model model)
{
   var entity = _context.Entity.Where(model.Expr).ToList(); // there  A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression exception
}
```

Comment: You should use Linqkit's `PredicateBuilder` for this. Now you work with `Func`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not going to use Predicate builder, you should use `Expand` in order to create a copy with expanded sub expressions

```
var expandedInput = input.Expr.Expand<Func<Entity,bool>>();
var exp = x => expandedInput.Invoke(x) && x.Name.Contains("A");
input.Expr = exp.Expand<Func<Entity,bool>>();
```

It's a bit ugly so, use `PredicateBuilder` as suggested if you can (it has an implicity cast to `Expression<TDelegate>`)

**Edit:** Added first expansion (which I thought was not necessary)

Comment: sorry, but now I have that : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.   in this line: input.Expr = exp.Expand<Func<Entity,bool>>();

Comment: What do you get in this case?
`var expandedInput = input.Expr.Expand<Func<Entity,bool>>();`
`var exp = x => expandedInput.Invoke(x) && x.Name.Contains("A");`
`input.Expr = exp.Expand<Func<Entity,bool>>();`